# Current level of block-chain

Tags: node, rpc, blockchain, block

How can I get an actual level of block-chain from not synced node (via RPC). i.e how get how many blocks left for synchronization my node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can request the current head of your node using `./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head` (and look for the `level` and `hash` information). Then, use your favorite block explorer to know the level of the current head.

Alternatively, the `./tezos-client bootstrapped` command aims to hang and return only when the node is synchronized.

Comment: I mean, can I do it via 1 rpc request.

Comment: No, there is no such RPC.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my goto command.

```
tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/ | jq -r '.header.level, .header.timestamp';date --iso-8601=seconds
```

The output will look something like:

```
544640
2019-07-31T10:53:57Z
2019-07-31T10:54:10+00:00
```

Which is the node's block level, the last block timestamp and your system's timestamp.

Run it a few times, waiting 10 - 20 seconds in between, to get an estimate on the time remaining to catch up.